# Select control doesn't show when published in Azure

Tags: html, angular, azure, select, formgroups

I have got a weird situcation here. I have a select control on a web page with angular. It shows correctly in local environment.
However, when I published it to Azure, The select control does not show correctly.

This is local showing.
[image: local web, show select control correctly]

This is on Azure site showing.
[image: Azure site, cannot show select control correctly]

This is inspect of select control on local site. Which looks good.
[image: Local html element inspect]

This is inspect of select control on Azure site. As it can be seen that, the select control is empty.
[image: Azure html element inspect]

Here is the html for select control, I create a component for customize showing.

```
<div class="dynamic-field row" [formGroup]="group">
  <label class="col-form-label" [ngClass]="'col-'+config.labelSize" *ngIf="config.labelSize!==0">{{ config.label }}</label>
  <div [ngClass]="'col-'+ (12 - (config.labelSize||0))">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      <div class="input-group-prepend" *ngIf="config.prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" *ngIf="!config.prependConfig" [innerHTML]="config.prepend"></span>
        <span class="input-group-text cursor-pointer" *ngIf="config.prependConfig" cspsDynamicFormModalLink [innerHTML]="config.prepend"
              [config]="config.prependConfig"></span>
      </div>
      <select [formControlName]="config.name" class="form-control">
        <option [ngValue]="undefined" *ngIf="config.placeholder">{{ config.placeholder }}</option>
        <option [ngValue]="option.key" *ngFor="let option of options">
          {{ option.value }}
        </option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group-append" *ngIf="config.append">
        <span class="input-group-text" *ngIf="!config.appendConfig" [innerHTML]="config.append"></span>
        <span class="input-group-text cursor-pointer" *ngIf="config.appendConfig" cspsDynamicFormModalLink [innerHTML]="config.append"
              [config]="config.appendConfig"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-select',
  templateUrl: 'form-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-select.component.css']
})
export class FormSelectComponent implements Field, OnInit {
  config: FieldConfig;
  group: FormGroup;
  options: { key: any, value: string }[];

  ngOnInit() {
    const sorter = {
      asc: (a: { value: string }, b: { value: string }) => { return a.value === b.value ? 0 : (a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1) },
      desc: (a: { value: string }, b: { value: string }) => { return a.value === b.value ? 0 : (a.value < b.value ? 1 : -1) },
      none: undefined
    }

    this.config.sortOptions = this.config.sortOptions || 'none';

    if (this.config.options)
      this.options = this.config.options.sort(sorter[this.config.sortOptions]);
    else
      this.options = [];
  }

}
```

Could anyone give me some suggestions? Or tell me what's going on?
Thanks